# How to fix "unexpected token" error in HQL Query

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to do this SQL statement:

```
select reimb_id, first_name, last_name, amount, type_id, description, 
             submitted, status_id, resolved
    from ers.reimbursement
    left join ers.users on author=user_id
    order by status_id
    limit 20;
```

in HQL. This is my attempt at that:

```
String hql = "Select reimb_id, firstname, lastname, amount, type_id, " +
"description, submit_date, status_id, resolve_date " +
"from Reimb " +
"join Reimb.Users as data " +
"order by data.status_id desc";

Query q = session.createQuery(hql).setMaxResults(20);
```

However when I hit this HQL statement I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [data.status_id],
>   unexpected token [data] [Select reimb_id, firstname, lastname, amount,
>   type_id, description, submit_date, status_id, resolve_date from
>   com.ers.pojos.Reimb join Reimb.Users as data order by data.status_id
>   desc]

If I remove the data expressions I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode   +-[IDENT] IdentNode:
>   'firstname' {originalText=firstname}

I've been using this to try and fix it to no avail: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

Here are my relevant Java classes and variables (at least the ones that are relevant)

My Reimb Java class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reimbursement", schema = "ers")
public class Reimb {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "reimb_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int reimb_id;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private double amount;

    @Column(name = "submitted")
    private Timestamp submit_date;

    @Column(name = "resolved")
    private Timestamp resolve_date;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "status_id")
    private int status_id;

    @Column(name = "type_id")
    private int type_id;
```

My Users java class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users", schema = "ers")
public class Users {

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastname;
```

Comment: shouldn't this line "from Reimb " +  be "from Reimbursement AS Reimb " +

Comment: From my understanding, HQL uses the Java class and variable names. In this case the class that Reimbursement is mapped to is called Reimb

Comment: Changing it to Reimbursement as Reimb gives me this exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'firstname' {originalText=firstname}

If I change firstname to match up with the table column (first_name), I get the same exception except it says first_name instead of firstname.